# Jetty TLS 1.0 and Client TLS 1.2

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

A SOAP web service is running on jetty and it supports TLS 1.0 only. A standalone client was upgraded to use TLS 1.2 only. Now the client is not able to communicate with the server. Is it possible to change Jetty's configuration to support TLS 1.2 without changing code on the SOAP web service? How do I go about configuring this?

Comment: Are you sure that something *inside the web service* is configured so that `it supports TLS 1.0 only`? Usually web service frameworks do not control such lower level details, they happily live in their own level.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.2 will require Java 8 at a minimum.

On the Jetty server side, you'll also want to be careful about which ciphers you include/exclude on the `SslContextFactory` to not exclude the ciphers that TLS 1.2 require.